# MSChart: ChartImageHandler pros/cons of the different storage settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I'm using the MSChart Control in a Web Project. I saw that there are 3 different storage mode settings: file/memory/session. I couldn't find any information about the pros/cons or the impact of the settings.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found that Scott Mitchell has the best write up on this topic: [Using Microsoft's Chart Controls in an ASP.NET Application: Rendering the Chart](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205231110/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081909-1.aspx). VERY useful info. I'd recommend reading the whole multipart series.

Answer (score 3):

The two links below have some good general information about the ImageHandler and also list the author of it, as well as a link to the Chart forum.  This looks like the authoritative source for ChartImageHandler information.

Much of the information is a duplicate on the two links.  The first one is the more recent, and the second link is the msdn blog of the author.

http://blogs.msdn.com/deliant/archive/2008/12/02/managing-chart-generated-images-with-chart-image-handler.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/deliant/