# Where should temp files created by the MS Chart control go?

Tags: asp.net, config, mschart

The default location:

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
```

is fine for development, but not so good for deploying on IIS.   I found a forum post that mentioned you could drop the path altogether, which dumps the temp file(s) directly in the root of my project

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
```

I don't want to clutter up my root folder though, so I am settling on this for now:

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;url=~/App_Data/ChartImageTemp/;" />
```

Thoughts or what are other people doing?  I'm a little curious as to why this is even a configurable option.  I am using .net 3.5, maybe this is different in 4.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A related question:

[MSChart: ChartImageHandler pros/cons of the different storage settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399809/mschart-chartimagehandler-pros-contras-of-the-different-storage-settings)

Pointed me to an article by Scott Mitchell:

https://web.archive.org/web/20201205231110/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081909-1.aspx

I've decided to use the "memory" option, so no files or paths to configure:

```
   <appSettings> 
      <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;deleteAfterServicing=true;"/> 
   </appSettings>
```

Comment: If you use web gardens, you're supposed to use file storage, but the control is buggy and doesn't really support web gardens regardless.

Comment: Good to know, but we have one production web server and one production db server here :)

Comment: Web Gardens is kind of a "web farm on a single server".  You just open up the IIS admin and select the # of processes you want to run.

Comment: Isn't there a problem using memory option if you choose to print the charts?  I believe that some versions of IE won't print them.

Comment: Prints OK on IE8.  With IE6, might have to set deleteAfterServicing to false http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/MSWinWebChart/thread/c3d9972c-0e88-4177-ae0b-7a2ebe6afe15